Firemonkey Image to Path conversion
Some time ago I stumbled upon a nice method to convert images - simple ones - to some kind of path. I did not give it the right attention, and now I should need it to simplify the program I'm writing.
This method was one of some FMX objects methods, but some time has passed and I don't remember this occurrence correctly.
I looked into the documentations for hous without findng what I'm looking for. All the references to "path" that I have found are related to the file paths (folder names) and not to the graphic vectors.
I tried also "vector", "convert" and many other terms.
Is there anyone who can point me to the right direction on how to convert an image to a vector ? Do you know libraries of components that can be used for this purpose?
Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Are you thinking of a Delphi-only method, or a third-party tool?  If the former, any chance you're actually thinking of converting text to a path?  You can certainly do that in FMX.
